# Cannot find module 'webpack-cli'

Tags: firebase, webpack, ecmascript-6

I want to make es6 into my project so I used this tutorial [this tutorial](https://medium.com/netscape/firebase-cloud-functions-with-typescript-and-webpack-7781c882a05b)
and when i try to write 'webpack' in cmd I get the error

```
    Done in 8.99s.
{ Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at runCommand.then.result (C:\Users\adirz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:62:14)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

package.json

```
   {
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~5.12.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^2.5.3",
    "webpack": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.14",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

my folder structure

[image]

Answer (score 62):

Try using: `npm i -g webpack-cli`.

Here is the official issue on github: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/191

Comment: This generates tons of "gyp" and "pre-gyp" errors :(

Comment: I had to globally install webpack along with webpack-cli to resolve this issue. That resolved my issue, but left with a query in my mind. When webpack-cli is a project dependency, why should we install it globally?

Answer (score 38):

Link globally installed package to your project

```
npm link webpack-cli
```

Comment: Great, if u are here because of php laravel, after the above command , run : ```npm run dev```

Answer (score 2):

This solved the problem for me

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm i -g webpack-cli
```

https://flaviocopes.com/npm-fix-missing-write-access-error/

Comment: There's a minor security risk with this approach: if your user is compromised (eg. if you install a virus/malware/etc. or if someone "hacks" you), they'll have access to your `node_modules` folder (normally they wouldn't; only a super user can change it).  This could let them replace libraries, and if those replaced libraries were ever run by a super user, the attacker would have total control of your computer .... in practice I'd imagine that's a *very small* risk (unless you work at the NSA or something it's unlikely an attacker would be looking for this) ... but it is a small risk.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. For me the answer was to ensure that the whole path to my project is free of spaces, ampersands(&) or any other weird characters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me it was that I was not using 'sudo' permissions.
If you are using linux based system try typing `sudo npm i -g webpack-cli`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Yarn** instead **NPM** to run **Webpack** globally, you can install webpack using the following commands:

```
yarn global add webpack
```

and or

```
yarn global add webpack-cli
```